# Class in JAR file not Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

### Problem Statement

The class from a JAR file is not getting autowired. Spring version used is 3.0

```
Classes Involved : InventoryController > ProductService > ProductManager > ProductDao
```

### Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.site.dao.ProductDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
```

### Modules

- `site-admin` is a `webapp`
- site-services (`jar` file)
- site-dao (`jar` file)

`InventoryController` is a class in the admin `webapp` which depends on `ProductService` from `site-service-1.0.jar` (`ProductService` and `ProductManager` is in `site-service-1.0.jar`).

`ProductService` depends on `ProductManager` which in turn depends on `ProductDao` which is in `site-dao-1.0.jar` (`ProductDao` is in `site-dao-1.0.jar`. At runtime the ProductDao is not getting autowired).

The `SimpleProductManager` references `ProductDao`, but at runtime its not getting loaded. The stacktrace is defined above
Need help/suggestions on what could be the issue

### Classes involved in this dependencies

```
InventoryController > ProductService > ProductManager > ProductDao
```

- `InventoryController`

  ```
  package com.site.admin.controllers;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.util.List;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.ui.Model;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
  import com.site.core.controller.ProductService;
  import com.site.domain.catalog.Product;

  @Controller
  public class InventoryController {

      @RequestMapping(value="/addproduct", method=RequestMethod.POST )
      public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute Product product, Model model) {
          List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
          products.add(product);

          model.addAttribute("products", products);
          return "addproductsuccess";
      }

      @RequestMapping(value="/showproductform", method=RequestMethod.GET)
      public String getProductForm() {
          return "addproduct";
      }

      @InitBinder
      public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
          SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          dateFormat.setLenient(false);
          binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
      }

      @Autowired
      private ProductService productService;

      public void setProductService(ProductService productService) {
          this.productService = productService;
      }
  }
  ```
- `ProductService`

  ```
  package com.site.core.controller;

  import java.util.List;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

  import com.site.core.manager.ProductManager;
  import com.site.domain.catalog.Product;

  @Service
  public class ProductService {

      @Autowired
      private ProductManager productManager;

      @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/products")
      @ResponseBody
      public List<Product> getProducts() {
          return productManager.getProducts();
      }

      @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/product/{productId}")
      @ResponseBody       
      public List<Product> getProductItems(@PathVariable int productId) {
          return productManager.getProductItems(productId);
      }

      @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/items")
      @ResponseBody
      public List<Product> getAllItems() {
          return productManager.getAllItems();
      }

      @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/items/{itemId}")
      @ResponseBody
      public Product getItem(@PathVariable int itemId) {
          return productManager.getItem(itemId);
      }

      public void setProductManager(ProductManager productManager) {
          this.productManager = productManager;
      }
  }
  ```
- `SimpleProductManager`

  ```
  package com.site.core.manager;
  import java.util.List;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
  import com.site.dao.ProductDao;
  import com.site.domain.catalog.Product;

  @Component
  public class SimpleProductManager implements ProductManager {

      @Autowired
      private ProductDao productDao;

      public List<Product> getProducts() {
          List<Product> products = productDao.getProducts();
          return products;
      }

      public Product getProduct(int productId) {
          Product product = productDao.getProduct(productId);
          return product;
      }

      public List<Product> getAllItems() {
          return productDao.getItems();
      }

      public List<Product> getProductItems(int productId) {
          return productDao.getItemsByProductId(productId);
      }

      public Product getItem(int itemId) {
          return productDao.getItem(itemId);
      }

      public void setProductDao(ProductDao productDao) {
          this.productDao = productDao;
      }
  }
  ```
- `SimpleProductDaoImpl`

  ```
  package com.site.dao;

  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;

  import com.site.dao.data.extractor.ProductSkuExtractor;
  import com.site.domain.catalog.Product;
  import com.site.domain.catalog.Sku;

  public class SimpleProductDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements ProductDao {

      // methods and setter/getters

      private String insertProduct;
      private String selectActiveProducts;
      private String selectProduct;
      private String updateProduct;
      private String deleteProduct;
      private String selectAllItems;
      private String selectItemById;
      private String selectItemsByProductId;
  }
  ```
- Application context defined in `admin` module (aka `webapp`)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

      <mvc:annotation-driven />
      <context:annotation-config />
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.site" />

      <!-- **************************************************************************** -->
      <!-- ******************* Thymeleaf specific configuration *********************** -->
      <!-- **************************************************************************** -->

      <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
          <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
          <property name="order" value="1"/>
          <property name="prefix" value="/templates/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
          <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
          <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
          <property name="order" value="1" />
          <property name="viewNames" value="*" />
      </bean>

  </beans>
  ```
- `Dao` Context

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

      <bean id="storeDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
          <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/storeDS" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="simpleProductDao" class="com.site.dao.SimpleProductDaoImpl">
          <property name="dataSource" ref="storeDS" />
          <property name="insertProduct">
              <value><![CDATA[insert into product(name, label, show_on_site, type_id, start_date, end_date, fake_end_date, updated_by, updated) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,now())]]></value>
          </property>
          <property name="selectActiveProducts">
              <value><![CDATA[select p.product_id, p.name as product_name, p.label, p.start_date, p.end_date, p.fake_end_date, p.image, pt.name from product p, product_type pt, sku s where now() between p.start_date and p.end_date and p.show_on_site = 'Y' and p.type_id = pt.type_id and s.product_id = p.product_id group by product_id]]></value>
          </property>
          <property name="selectProduct">
              <value><![CDATA[select product_id, name, label, show_on_site, start_date, end_date from product where product_id = ? ]]></value>
          </property>
          <property name="updateProduct">
              <value><![CDATA[update product set name = ?, label = ?, show_on_site = ?, type_id = ?, start_date = ?, end_date = ? where product_id = ?]]></value>
          </property>
          <property name="deleteProduct">
              <value><![CDATA[delete from product where product_id = ?]]></value>
          </property>
          <property name="selectItemById">
              <value><![CDATA[select p.product_id, p.name as product_name, p.image as product_image, s.description, s.image as sku_image, s.retail_price, s.sale_price, s.quantity, s.name as item_name, s.sku_id, po.name as option_name, po.product_option_id as option_id, pov.name as option_value, pov.product_option_value_id as option_value_id from product p join sku s on p.product_id = s.product_id and s.sku_id = ? left join product_option_value pov on s.product_option_value_id = pov.product_option_value_id left join product_option po on pov.product_option_id = po.product_option_id]]></value>
          </property>
          <property name="selectAllItems">
              <value><![CDATA[select p.product_id, p.name as product_name, p.image as product_image, s.description, s.image as sku_image, s.retail_price, s.sale_price, s.quantity, s.name as item_name, s.sku_id, po.name as option_name, po.product_option_id as option_id, pov.name as option_value, pov.product_option_value_id as option_value_id from product p join sku s on p.product_id = s.product_id left join product_option_value pov on s.product_option_value_id = pov.product_option_value_id left join product_option po on pov.product_option_id = po.product_option_id]]></value>
          </property>
          <property name="selectItemsByProductId">
              <value><![CDATA[select p.product_id, p.name as product_name, p.image as product_image, s.description, s.image as sku_image, s.retail_price, s.sale_price, s.quantity, s.name as item_name, s.sku_id, po.name as option_name, po.product_option_id as option_id, pov.name as option_value, pov.product_option_value_id as option_value_id from product p join sku s on p.product_id = s.product_id and p.product_id = ? left join product_option_value pov on s.product_option_value_id = pov.product_option_value_id left join product_option po on pov.product_option_id = po.product_option_id]]></value>
          </property>     
      </bean>
  </beans>
  ```

### web.xml

```
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-clas‌​s>
 <init-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-    
  value>classpath*:/**/*spring-context.xml,classpath*:com/**/*spring-conte‌​xt.xml</param-    
  value> </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet> 

 <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name> 
 <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern> 
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: If it cannot be found your xml file isn't loaded or loaded in the wrong context. Post your web.xml.

Comment: Add it to your post not as comment...

Answer (score 2):

in Your service Implementation you should define service name in annotation
i hope so it will be help full

```
@Service("UserService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService
```

in your code you see below code

ProductService

```
@Service("ProductService")
public class ProductService {
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue which was causing this. The dao context was defined in file dao-spring-service-context.xml which was not in accordance with the contextConfigLocation defined in web.xml

```
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath*:/**/*spring-context.xml,classpath*:com/**/*spring-context.xml
</param-value>
```

Thanks all for the help and guidance

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing @Component on your ProductDao

something like this

@Component
public class ProductDao
{
..............
}